# JMeter - Menu item « What's this node » not working

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

About JMeter Help menu, there's an option`What's this node?`

It doesn't seem to be working, it does nothing when focus on any component, also using shortcut Ctrl+W.

I didn't find any documentation of it use cases, but it looks like a bug, Someone use it somehow?

To get component help I can right click component and choose Help.

It tested on JMeter 4 and previous versions (3.3, 3.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This menu is for developers in fact.

It will display in jmeter.log and in console output the full class name of selected element and it gui full class name.

Comment: Interesting, so it can be pasted to `gui.quick_X` for example